# How to use net.java.ao.Query to query issues?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have this select in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT "field_1", "field_2","field_3", MIN(COALESCE(NULLIF("field_4",'') ,'TBD')) MINDP,MIN("field_5") MINBOD FROM "MY_TABLE" GROUP BY "field_1", "field_2","field_3"
```

And I want to use net.java.ao.Query to query my database. My function:

```
import net.java.ao.Query;

    public List<myClass> find() {

        String SQL = "SELECT \"field_1\", \"field_2\",\"field_3\", MIN(COALESCE(NULLIF(\"field_4\",'') ,'TBD')) MINDP,MIN(\"field_5\") MINBOD FROM \"MY_TABLE\" GROUP BY \"field_1\", \"field_2\",\"field_3\""

        return newArrayList(ao.find(myClass.class, Query.select(SQL)));

    }
```

The problem is: this code return all issues of my table.

When I run this SQL in postgreSQL console it works fine.

My code has different results than SQL console.

Does anybody know why is this happening?

Comment: Actually I changed my code to: return newArrayList(ao.findWithSQL(myClass.class, "ANY_INT_column_inRESULT",SQL)); and it worked :) but I still want to know why this is not working

Answer (score 0):

- Old question but if somebody steps over this -

`Query.select()` is not meant to put plain `SQL` into. It is more of a builder to create 'database independant' query. See some examples here: [Finding entities](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/finding-entities/)

```
public MyEntity[] findMyEntities(String fieldValue) {
    final Query query = Query.select()
            .where("FIELD_VALUE = ?", fieldValue);
    // evaluates to something like this
    // SELECT * FROM MY_ENTITY WHERE FIELD_VALUE = x;
    return ao.find(MyEntity.class, query);
}
```

This is why there's another method (which you used in your comment), that can handle plain SQL (`findWithSQL`).

Attention `Query` and `find()` often do not work as expected, so you might not get your original query to work using the query builder.